# Debian 10 install what is default account and password?

Tags: debian, installation, default, account

The account is supposed to be debian but I see no password suggestion anywhere.

I tried root/toor with no luck.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

right! I did the same.. it's:

user/live

yw :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no default account / password in Debian.

The root account may not have been enabled if no password were provided during install: as stated in [the official wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Root)

> If no password was provided, no root account is enabled and the password of the first user created will be used for administration tasks.

Therefore you should log using the user you have created during the installation setup.

Comment: While installation it does not prompt me to create a user at all.

Comment: I found this answer helpful in creating a user after installation when one wasn't creating during the install process: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94466/didnt-have-to-specify-a-login-name-during-installation-now-it-asks-me-for-one